# Test ADO connection and reconnect prior to execution if needed, in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, database-connection, ado, adodb

I have the following VBScript (vbs):

```
Option Explicit

Dim cn, cmDB, rs
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQLDNSHere"
cn.Open
cn.CommandTimeout = 28800
Set cmDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmDB.CommandTimeout = 28800

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorType = 2

MsgBox "disconnected network here then clicked ok to proceed"
MsgBox cn.State
MsgBox cmDB.State
MsgBox rs.State

Set rs = cn.Execute("select * from test;")

WScript.Quit
```

At the first message box I would like to simulate losing a connection to our database. Possible causes could be that the database is down or the LAN is down, etc. In other words, I want to test if the connection is in good order so a valid execute statement will succeed. The msgboxes above never change after I disconnect from the network.

The only way I can currently do it is to `Execute` after a `On Error Resume Next`, then look at the `Err.Number`. Is there a way to test the connection prior to the execute so I can reconnect then `execute` like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim cn, cmDB, rs
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=PostgreSQLDNSHere"
cn.Open
cn.CommandTimeout = 28800
Set cmDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmDB.CommandTimeout = 28800

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.CursorType = 2

MsgBox "disconnected network here then clicked ok to proceed"

If cn.State = ?? Then
   'reconnect here
End If
Set rs = cn.Execute("select * from test;")

WScript.Quit
```

EDIT1:
I also tried setting the recordset after disconnect, but that didn't change the message box result in the first code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The `State` property indicates just the state of the connection on the *client side*. AFAIK you need to execute a query in order to detect whether or not the server is still available.

```
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 1;"

On Error Resume Next
Set rs = cmd.Execute
If Err Then
  If Err.Number = &h80004005 Then
    'server side disconnected -> re-open
    cn.Close
    cn.Open
  Else
    WScript.Echo "Unexpected error 0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End If
```

Note that you may need to re-assign the re-opened connection to the object using it.

Note also that the above does just the most basic reconnect by closing and re-opening the connection. In real-world scenarios you may want to be able to retry at least a couple times if the reconnect fails as well (e.g. because the network or server hasn't come back up yet).

Comment: Thanks! I added another answer that does what you suggest. If you want to clean up my code from that answer and put in your answer, feel free and I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ansgar's suggestion I am posting code that will "try at least a couple times". The function will return the connection object if it successfully reconnects or the connection is already good, else `nothing` after trying a user input number of times and waiting a user input number of seconds between tries:

```
Option Explicit

dim cn, cmDB, rs
set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  

cn.ConnectionString= "DSN=PostgreSQLDsn" 
cn.open 
cn.CommandTimeout = 28800
Set cmDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmDB.CommandTimeout = 28800

set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.CursorType = 2

msgbox "disconnected internet here then clicked ok to proceed"    

set cn = TestReOpenConnection(cn,"DSN=PostgreSQLDsn",28800,2,100)

if cn is nothing then
    msgbox "not good"
    WScript.Quit
end if

set rs = cn.execute("select * from test;")
msgbox "all good: " & rs.fields("x")

WScript.Quit

function TestReOpenConnection(cn,sDsn,iConnTimeOut,iWaitSecs,iTimesToTry)

    dim iWaitMilSecs 
    iWaitMilSecs = iWaitSecs * 1000
    dim bConnected  
    bConnected = false
    dim iTries
    iTries = 0
    dim rsTest
    set rsTest = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

    do while bConnected = false 

        On Error Resume Next

        Set rsTest = cn.execute("select 1;")
        If Err Then

            if iTries <> 0 then
                WScript.Sleep iWaitMilSecs 'if we tried once already, then wait 
            end if

            cn.Close
            set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
            cn.ConnectionString= sDsn

            On Error Resume Next
            cn.open 
            cn.CommandTimeout = iConnTimeOut
        else

            bConnected = true
            set TestReOpenConnection = cn
        End If
        iTries = iTries + 1
        if iTries > iTimesToTry then
            set TestReOpenConnection = nothing
            exit do
        end if
    loop

end function
```

This answer isn't necessary to the central question I asked, but I thought it would be useful to people viewing this in the future. Probably could use some cleaning up.